# Aggregation Queries

Tags: sqlite, aggregate-functions, sqlite.swift

Is it possible to do the following query in SQLite.Swift without resorting to arbitrary SQL (which I do have working but would prefer to avoid)?

```
select table1.id, sum(table1.col1*table2.col2)
from table1, table2
where table1.id=table2.id
group by table1.id
```

I've attempted the following: the SQL (through `asSQL()`) appears to be correct, but I can't find a way to reference the aggregate column from the returned row.

```
let query = table1.select(id, (table1[column1]*table2[column2]).sum
            .join(table2, on: table1[id] == table2[id])
            .group(id)
```

Can you alias columns somehow?

Comment: Edited to correct typo and column ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found the solution, and it only took me 2 days!

The way to alias a column in SQLite.swift is to use an expression.
The name of the expression becomes the column alias.

So instead of

```
let query = table1.select(id, (table1[column1]*table2[column2]).sum)
            .join(table2, on: table1[id] == table2[id])
            .group(id)
```

Use:

```
let aggrColumn = (table1[column1]*table2[column2]).sum
let query = table1.select(id, aggrColumn)
            .join(table2, on: table1[id] == table2[id])
            .group(id)
let results = try db.prepare(query)
for row in results {
    myAggrColumn = try row.get(aggrColumn)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
select id, sum(table1.col1*table2.col2)
from table1, table2
were table1.id=table2.id
group by id
```

Will result (**see below for corrections**) in 2 columns, namely **id** and **sum(table1,col*table2.col2)**

However both uses of id would be ambiguous as coded as there are two such source columns.
As such the query should be changed  (**see following code** whihc assumes you want the id from table1 (shouldn't matter if table2 were used due to the join))

Additionally **`were`** is not a keyword, it should be **`WHERE`**

An alias would likely make things easier you make an alias using the **`AS`** keyword. The folloiwng also includes **`AS mysumcolumn`** thus the resultant columns will be **id** and **mysumcolumn**

```
select table1.id, sum(table1.col1*table2.col2) AS mysumcolumn
from table1, table2
where table1.id=table2.id
group by table1.id
```

Running this with no data results in :-

[image]